# .htaccess and url rewrite with EasyPHP

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

i have some trouble with url rewriting with easyphp.
This is my enviroment configuration: OS win7, Apache 2.4.2. PHP 5.3.14.
httpd.conf

```
<Directory "${path}/www">
#
# Possible values for the Options directive are "None", "All",
# or any combination of:
#   Indexes Includes FollowSymLinks SymLinksifOwnerMatch ExecCGI MultiViews
#
# Note that "MultiViews" must be named *explicitly* --- "Options All"
# doesn't give it to you.
#
# The Options directive is both complicated and important.  Please see
# http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#options
# for more information.
#
Options Indexes FollowSymLinks

#
# AllowOverride controls what directives may be placed in .htaccess files.
# It can be "All", "None", or any combination of the keywords:
#   Options FileInfo AuthConfig Limit
#
AllowOverride All

#
# Controls who can get stuff from this server.
#
Require all granted
```

And rewrite module is loaded even from httpd.conf

..other modules..

```
#LoadModule remoteip_module modules/mod_remoteip.so
#LoadModule request_module modules/mod_request.so
#LoadModule reqtimeout_module modules/mod_reqtimeout.so
LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so
#LoadModule sed_module modules/mod_sed.so
#LoadModule session_module modules/mod_session.so
#LoadModule session_cookie_module modules/mod_session_cookie.so
#LoadModule session_crypto_module modules/mod_session_crypto.so
#LoadModule session_dbd_module modules/mod_session_dbd.so
```

..other modules..

And from phpinfo, mod_rewrite is loaded too

```
Loaded Modules  
core mod_win32 mpm_winnt http_core mod_so mod_access_compat 
mod_actions mod_alias mod_allowmethods mod_asis mod_auth_basic      
mod_authn_core mod_authn_file mod_authz_core mod_authz_groupfile 
mod_authz_host mod_authz_user mod_autoindex mod_cgi mod_dir mod_env
mod_include mod_isapi mod_log_config mod_mime mod_negotiation
mod_rewrite mod_setenvif mod_php5
```

In order to testing mod rewrite in main directory www i had created the file page.html and i traing to rewrtite it in home.html
My .htaccess rules in www directory are:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule "^index.html$" "page.html"
</IfModule>
```

Nothing append, in my browser url is http://127.0.0.1/page.html and not http://127.0.0.1/index.html

Can you help me?

Comment: Remove the rules from inside `<if`.. block

Comment: I tried but it does not work